# How can I assign values to a greek letter while writing a script in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, symbols

I would like to use `<-` to assign values to Greek letters or other symbols, just as I can assign a value the letter 'A'. Does a method exist for incorporating symbols into an R script?

I am writing scripts in RStudio.

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: Of course you can. I can use `δ <- 1` without problems in RStudio.

Comment: I believe that this is likely platform (locale?) dependent. Typically though, if you're on a non-Windows system using a UTF-8 locale, this should work as expected. On Windows, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible but perhaps a bit more annoying than using alpha, beta, gamma, etc.

```
greek <- c("α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ", "χ", "ψ", "ω")

for (g in greek) assign(g, toupper(g))

for (g in greek) print(paste(g, get(g), sep=":"))
[1] "α:Α"
[1] "β:Β"
[1] "γ:Γ"
[1] "δ:Δ"
[1] "ε:Ε"
[1] "ζ:Ζ"
[1] "η:Η"
[1] "θ:Θ"
[1] "ι:Ι"
[1] "κ:Κ"
[1] "λ:Λ"
[1] "μ:Μ"
[1] "ν:Ν"
[1] "ξ:Ξ"
[1] "ο:Ο"
[1] "π:Π"
[1] "ρ:Ρ"
[1] "σ:Σ"
[1] "τ:Τ"
[1] "υ:Υ"
[1] "φ:Φ"
[1] "χ:Χ"
[1] "ψ:Ψ"
[1] "ω:Ω"

GREEK <- toupper(greek)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gladwell For some reason the capital Delta acts weird on my system. I just realized I was able to use ALT and a 3-digit-number to create symbols